# Android : LinearLayout with weight inside a ScrollView

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I'm having this frustrating issue with my ScrollView, here is my hierarchy :

```
ScrollView (Vertical)
    LinearLayout (Vertical)
        ImageView weight= 0.5
        Whatever weight= 0.1
        Whatever weight= 0.2
        Whatever weight= 0.2
```

If I remove the ScrollView (and let the LinearLayout as main item), this work properly with any Image : The image takes 50% of the screen size, and the other Views take fill the rest.

However, when the ScrollView is here, the "weight" parameter is completely ignored if my Image is too tall : The image will do anything it can to fit the screen width, and then will be obviously too tall and take more than 50% of the screen. EDIT : actually, all the "weight" attributes seem ignored :

Without ScrollView:
[image]

With ScrollView:
[image]

I want the Linear Layout to fit perfectly without having to Scrolling. Is that possible ? I've tried to change some of the image option (scaleType, adjustViewBounds) but I didn't manage to have what I wanted.

Here's the whole xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/testing" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="I'M A TEST" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:text="I'M A TEST" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="I'M A TEST" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Note : I need the ScrollView because I'm using a PullToRefresh ScrollView

Comment: just out of curiosity, if you don't want to scroll, why do you need the scrollview?

Comment: Basically this^. Scrollview doesn't have dimension, it can be infinite. 50% of what do you expect your imageview to be? If it's a linear layout, it knows. ScrollView takes up as much space as it needs.

Comment: This doesn't seem right. Have a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html It might be what you need.

Comment: There's no sense in grouping a layout in a ScrollView, if you want it to be fixed.

Comment: I need this ScrollView because I'm using the PullToRefresh library using ScrollView.
I want my  image to be 50% of the screen size, when the user has not scrolled yet.

Comment: Then you are not going to have a fixed layout, as you already discovered by yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by adding a parent Linear Layout (and a main relativeLayout) :

```
    ScrollView (Vertical)
        LineaLayout
            LinearLayout (Vertical)
                ImageView weight= 0.5
                Whatever weight= 0.1
                Whatever weight= 0.2
                Whatever weight= 0.2
```

And setting programmatically the height of the child LinearLayout to the height of the screen with `childLinearLayout.getLayoutParams().height`

Comment: It will be great to understand the current behavior. I agreed, this solution worked!

Comment: Code (almost) always works; declarative stuff.... a lot less often :-) I am taking this route, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe it's too late but your problem could be solved by adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to your `ScrollView` :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Answer (score -1):

Try on this way .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="I&apos;M A TEST" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="I&apos;M A TEST" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="I&apos;M A TEST" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: But this wouldn't respect the 50%, 20%, 20%, 10% heights requirement.

Comment: Really... how is `wrap content` going to respect the percentages?